# Amp page rel=canonical pointing to non-amp auto Wordpress

Tags: php, amp-html

I am stuck with this thing.
I have the original page (article) in Wordpress that has rel="amphtml" in it inserted auto.
Now, I need to have from amp page a rel="canonical" pointing to the original one, and do this auto.
I have written this code to amp html:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
```

But this code makes AMP page to point to itself, and not to the original version.

Any thoughts? I am a bit new in this

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I will post it here, maybe another user will need it

I have added in amp html-start.php this (after head)

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
```